# Configure content management and content delivery on Sitecore 7.2

Tags: content-management, content-delivery

I am looking for a guideline on configuring CD and CM servers. Sitecore provided this guideline but it is for [Sitecore 8.0 and up](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_a_content_delivery_server).

I am looking for Sitecore 7.2 guideline. Please let me know if there's any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding some additional context, mentioned in other answers, the **[Sitecore Scaling Guide](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/scaling_guide_sc70_a4.pdf)** which is available on the old [Sitecore Developer Network](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%207/Scaling%20Guide.aspx) site is intended for versions of Sitecore 7.0 to 7.2.

In this guide, Chapter 2.4 specifically, talks about how to convert a CM instance (which is the standard Sitecore install) and make it a content delivery server.

Since this document has come out, there have been some enhancements that the community has provided.  One of them is the `SwitchMasterToWeb.config` which step 2.4.3 (and referencing Section 4.6) refer to, which you can download on the [SDN Scaling Guide Site](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/64/switchmastertoweb.zip).  A [Revised version of this config](https://gist.github.com/Adamsimsy/9251706) file was made available by Adam Simsy.

### Security Hardening

Additionally, while on the topic of setting up Content Delivery servers, when working in production environments, you also want to ensure you are paying attention to the [Sitecore Security Hardening Guide](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%207/Security%20Hardening%20Guide.aspx), which includes additional information specifically for hardening the security of Content Delivery servers.

Answer (score 6):

You can refer to the **Sitecore Scaling Guide** from SDN: https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/scaling_guide_sc70_a4.pdf

*P.s. Keep in mind that **http://doc.sitecore.net** contains documentation only for Sitecore 8+ versions.
Thus if you are looking for documentation for Sitecore versions prior to 8, you should refer to the **https://sdn.sitecore.net/***